# ArrayList ".add" and "<<" different behaviour in Groovy when accessing `super`

Tags: inheritance, arraylist, groovy

When using ArrayList in Groovy, it [seems that](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_lists) `<<` is an alias for `.add`, however in this small example it isn't:

```java
class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    @Override
    boolean add(Integer num) {
        println "I'm doing something cool here!"
    }

    boolean insert(Integer num) {
        println "I'm adding it for real"
        // super.add(num) works as expected
        super << num   
    }
}

def ml = new MyList();
ml.insert(100)
assert ml.size() == 1
```

Output:

```
I'm adding it for real
I'm doing something cool here!
Caught: Assertion failed: 

assert ml.size() == 1
       |  |      |
       [] 0      false

Assertion failed: 

assert ml.size() == 1
       |  |      |
       [] 0      false
```

If I use `super.add(num)` it passes the assertion and it prints only "I'm adding it for real"

Can someone explain to me why `super <<` is calling itself instead of parent class and why it is not added into the array when using `<<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you've overrode `ArrayList.add` method but broke the contract as well: you don't return anything from overridden method whereas an instance of `boolean` should be return.

`super.add(num)` works as expected because you call `ArrayList.add` directly.

`<<` is an alias for `add` in case of `List`. Now, `super << num` delegates the call to [`DefaultGroovyMethods`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L12196) which in turn invokes `add` on the `List`. But in this particular case not the `add` in `ArrayList` but `add` in `MyList` which as I wrote in the beginning breaks the `add` contract. The following piece of code works well:

```
class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    @Override
    boolean add(Integer num) {
        println "I'm doing something cool here!"
        return super.add(num)
    }

    boolean insert(Integer num) {
        println "I'm adding it for real"
        // super.add(num) works as expected
        super << num
    }
}

def ml = new MyList();
ml.insert(100)
assert ml.size() == 1
```

Comment: So then indeed there is a difference! I would have expected super << num to call ArrayList.add but instead it calls MyList.add... Is there any documentation about that behaviour?

Comment: @lepe, I see but it does not change anything in this particular case. You return a boolean value *without* modifying the list, so it fails expectedly.

Comment: Yes, that is why I opted to removed it again... I understand now where the issue comes from and why it is actually not added (size() not being increased) due to MyList.add being called instead the parent class. Thanks

Comment: @lepe, you're welcome. This is the case, you were not calling *original*, `add` anywhere which modifies the list.

Comment: do you think this is a bug or it is like that by design?

Comment: @lepe, no rather not. It's your job to keep the contracts of classes you extend.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I forgot to include the return value in `add`, but that doesn't change the fact that `super << num` is calling the child class first, while `super.add(num)` calls the parent class directly. I read they were the same, so I was expecting the `<<` behave exactly as `.add`.